# SQL rank calculation by row

Tags: sql

I have a table

| Name | count | rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| A | 4 | 2 |
| A | 7 | 3 |

I am trying to calculate new column D for the count with rank

- for rank 1, count = 2
- for rank 2, count = 4-2 =2
- for rank 3,  count = 7-2 -4 =1

The expected result should be

| Name | count | rank | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| A | 7 | 3 | 1 |

I am trying to use patrion by but it's not working

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       2 * count - SUM(count) OVER (ORDER BY rank) D
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c6a3c587c188f6ecb7ed05ef46ece916).